# simpleXML how to get feed

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to get the `title` and the `link` from this XML feed:

```
<item>
  <title>A title</title>
  <link>http://example.com</link>
</item>
```

How is this possible? I am new to PHP and I'm trying to figure it out. This is what I have so far.

```
 <?php
     include 'http://example/forum/index.php?action=.xml;type=rss';

     $channel = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

      echo $channel->$item[0]->title;
?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: To start, it's item not $item

Answer (score 2):

`include` just drops a file into the output from the script. So don't use that.

`new SimpleXMLElement` creates an *element* and you want a document. So don't use that.

`$xmlstr` is undefined. So don't use that.

Use [`simplexml_load_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
foreach($xml->item as $items){
      echo $items->title;
}
```